# how to disable a link from special url jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable links which it's link to product. My links like follows.

`<a href="http://www.example.com/?product=product01">
<a href="http://www.example.com/?product=sample-product02">
<a href="http://www.example.com/?product=product03">`

I want disable if url like `http://www.example.com/?product=******` using jquery

Help me Thanks

Comment: Could you take a stab and edit in some code to do this? Even wrong code is easier to help you since it's more clear what you don't get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var links = $('a[href^="http://www.example.com/?product="]');

// method 1
//links.removeAttr('href');

// method 2
links.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Example here: [fiddlejs](http://jsfiddle.net/u4Lhu1b2/1/)

I recommend you to read jQuery Attribute Selectors [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) page.

Comment: Thanks you very much. Can it keep as a only text?

Comment: What do you mean to keep as only text?, with css you can override link styles; if you don't have a css class, you can add it with jQuery. Ex: links.addClass('normal-text');

Comment: I could disable links using this Jquery, links.addClass('remove-links'); and CSS a.remove-links{
 pointer-events: none;
      cursor: default;
 }

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative and further to Cadence96's answer, you can use `replaceWith` to change all links to text like this:

```
var links = $('a[href^="http://www.example.com/?product="]');

links.replaceWith(function(){
    return '<div class="new-item">' + $(this).html() + '</div>'; // or wrap with a <div> or whatever you want
});
```

Comment: Why the minus? I think this answer is very good and works.

Comment: @Cadence96, I'm not sure what the downvoter thinks :) But hey, with your comment like this, it's enough for me.

Comment: I would return it adding some wrapping html. http://jsfiddle.net/u4Lhu1b2/2/

Comment: Thanks @Cadence96 for the improvement :)

Answer (score 0):

why put the links in in the first place ? dont need jquery, just use css to display none or visibility hidden...Jquery example added aswell

```js
$('a[href^="http://www.Jqueryexample.com"]').hide();
```

```css
a[href^="http://www.example.com/?product"]{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.example.com/?product=product01"></a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/?product=sample-product02"></a>
<a href="http://www.Jqueryexample.com/?product=sample-product02">Jquery example</a>

  <a href="http://www.example2.com/?product=product03">example2 domain</a><br>
  <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
```

Comment: I don't want hide the links. I want to keep as a text. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a overkill, but i would do it this way:

1. It only takes the parameter of the ulr into consideration
2. You can easily add further links to disable to the disableProductLink-array
3. If you like already add a class in the each loop, for diferent styling on the element.

So here is the js-part:

```
function getParameterByName( name,href )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var disableProductLink = new Array("product01", "product02");

$('a').each(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var product = getParameterByName('product', url);
    if(disableProductLink.indexOf(product) != -1){        
        $(this).on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $(this).addClass('notAvaible');
    }        
});
```

Running example under: http://jsfiddle.net/6m7zh1fx/1